A man with two lovers, they find out and confront him
I saw this movie during the '90s in (I think) HBO. I remember all or most of the film is set up in the guy's appartment, and it felt like it was an adapted theater play.
In the appartment, the two women meet by chance and decide to wait for him to arrive and confront him.
Original language: english

Can you recall anything else? What actresses/actors were in it or what did they look like? How did they meet? Was it a comedy or drama ?

Not really, I though the guy was Robert Downey Jr. but I couldn't find any movie like that with him. But so many years after I don't know if I remember or I'm filling gaps. Maybe the guy just looked like him.

Sounds like Two Girls and A Guy. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0124179/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_54 It is set in the 90's and is contained inside and outside of the apartment. Great cast.

based on @Mauricio Pasquier Juan saying he looked like Robert Downey Jr, and your answer has him in the cast, I'd say this is the correct answer.

Damn, I swear I went to IMDB and search through his entire filmography. I don't know how I missed it :(
